How can I read and use the value of pipeline environment variable into my PowerShell and use that value subsequently on my URL of API Call?
I have created an pipeline variable on my release pipeline and I am able to read that value in my powershell script as well, the problem is that the value of that variable is not being populated/passed into my URL of API call. Script as below;
$testRunId = $env:runID   --> **runID** is the pipeline variable
$organization = "XXXX"
$project ="XXXX"
$pat = "XXXX"

# Headers for the API call
$headers = @{
    Authorization = "Basic " + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$pat"))
    "Content-Type" = "application/json"
}

# Mark the test run as completed with a comment
$completeRunUri = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/test/runs/$testRunId?api-version=6.0"
$body = @{
    state = "Completed"
    comment = "Automated tests have been executed and results updated."
} | ConvertTo-Json

Write-Output "Marking the test run as completed with a comment at: $completeRunUri"
Write-Output "Payload: $body"

try {
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $completeRunUri -Method Patch -Headers $headers -Body $body -ErrorAction Stop

    if ($response -eq $null) {
        Write-Error "Failed to mark test run as completed"
    } else {
        Write-Output "Test run marked as completed successfully"
    }
} catch {
    Write-Error "Error marking test run as completed: $_"
}

# Write an output to the pipeline log
Write-Output "Test results have been updated and test run marked as completed for test run ID $testRunId"

I wanted to pass that value of $testRunId into my URL as mentioned above (https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/test/runs/$testRunId?api-version=6.0)

Please show us where/how you're setting the pipeline variable and the powershell task where you're running the script.

Is the pipeline variable being set in the same job where the script is run?

You can try the suggestion in my answer below. @ClinOneTest2

Due to the question mark (?) that immediately follows after the expression, the expression to reference a PowerShell variable ($varName) might not be recognized as normal. Changing the expression to ${varName} can avoid this problem. Just like as the suggestion in my answer below. @ClinOneTest2

Did any of the answers below solved your problem @ClinOneTest2 ?

Update the line
$completeRunUri = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/test/runs/$testRunId?api-version=6.0"

to
$completeRunUri = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/test/runs/${testRunId}?api-version=6.0"

should work.

it worked @Bright

@ClinOneTest2, Glad that my answer can work for you.

@ClinOneTest2, Maybe, you can accept this answer. This could be also helpful for other people who are looking for a solution of the similar questions.

@ClinOneTest2 if this answer helped you consider accepting the answer and/or upvoting it.

This looks like a similar issue to Cannot set ENV variable in azure pipeline with value from other step.
Try setting an environment variable at the task level and then use it in your script.
Example:
steps:
  - pwsh: |
      $runID="123456"
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=runID]$runID"
    displayName: 'Set pipeline variable runID'
  - pwsh: |
      Write-Host "Run ID: $(runID)"
    displayName: 'Use pipeline variable'
  - pwsh: |
      Write-Host "Run ID: ${Env:testRunId}"
    displayName: 'Use task environment variable using Powershell syntax'
    env:
      # assign the pipeline variable $(runID) to task environment variable ${Env:testRunId}
      testRunId: $(runID)
  - bash: |
      Write-Host "Run ID: ${testRunId}"
    displayName: 'Use task environment variable using bash syntax'
    env:
      # assign the pipeline variable $(runID) to task environment variable ${testRunId}
      testRunId: $(runID)

Please note that the syntax changes if you're trying to use the pipeline variable in a different job or stage.
Please refer to the linked answer for more details.
